# Run same cucumber scenario multiple times

Tags: ruby, webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am trying to run same scenario for like 1000 times. What i want to test is whether application is stable if I login and logout for n number of times. I have come up with a way but that doesn't look neat and clean. I want to generate a report as well for the 1000 executions in same HTML.

This is what I've done

Cucumber Step:

```
    When I login "1000" number of times
```

And in my step definition is :

```
    successful_attempts = 0
    unsuccessful_attempts = 0
    attempt_login = attempt_login.to_i

    attempt_login.times do 

      visit_page(Login)

      on_page Login do |page|
        page.login_with username, password
        page.logout? ? (page.logout;successful_attempts+= 1) : unsuccessful_attempts+= 1
      end

    end

    puts "Total Attempts :  #{attempt_login}"
    puts "Successful Attempts : #{successful_attempts}"
    puts "Unsuccessful Attempts : #{unsuccessful_attempts}"

    fail if unsuccessful_attempts > 0
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in Cucumber? It seems like a unusual use case for Cucumber.

Comment: i have an existing automation suite with 200 test cases and have to add this in the suite..  I know this is not a good cucumber scenario but I've to figure out a way.

Comment: Fair enough. How are you expecting the report to look? Are you expecting to see a line in the report for each individual login attempt or just a summary?

Comment: actually anything will do, i came up with the above way for reporting.

Comment: Okay. Then I do not understand what your question is. If it already works, why do you need to make a change?

Comment: problem with this is, I've to keep begin rescue blocks to deal with intermittent issues like element not found. In case of any such issues, the do block will break if i don't keep begin rescue block and that doesn't look neat. I just wanted to check if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: If the "login 1000 times" given step worked as expected according to the wording,  it would login 1000 times, THEN proceed to the next step.. not what you want.

Comment: this is the only step i'll execute. Sometimes i get element not found error message. In such case, do loop will stop. for now, I've kept begin rescue block so that the script doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your case is a bit unusual. If it were me I would try to use ['Scenario Outline'](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines), where each Scenario takes in a parameter called 'Attempt' for example:

```
Scenario Outline: verify login 1000 times
  Given I am not logged in
  When I log in with attempt <attempt>
  Then ...

  Examples:
    | attempt |
    | 1       |
    | 2       |
    | ...     |
    | 1000    |
```

Step definition:

```
When(/^I log in with attempt (\d+)$/) do |attempt|
    ...
end
```

The upside of this is you have a clean report of which attempt it failed, possibly keeping different exception logs, and 1 failed case will not block other cases. The downside of this is that you would need to write some script to generate that table of 1000 numbers.

Comment: an irb session with `1000.times { |i| puts i }` would generate your numbers for you...

Comment: Something along these lines is likely your best solution.  I would put that scenario into its very own feature file, since it will be a bit ugly, and give it a tag so you can run it on its own, or include/exclude as needed.

Comment: using scenario outline will definitely make it look ugly. Downside is I've to write 1000 rows and the user will be having tough time if he/she have to increase number of attempts (like increasing attempts to 2000 or more). That's why i came up with the above step so that i can control the number of attempts.